# PHP - $_SESSION['var1'] is not set on index.php

Tags: php, javascript, html

So I have the index.php page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['var1'])) {
echo "session not started...";
die();
} else {
echo "session started"; 
die();
}
?>
```

It also has a login form that leads to following login script:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ..blahblah");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$_SESSION['var1'] = 1;
}
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['var1'])) {
echo "wrong login or password";
} else {
header("location:http://mysite.com");
}
?>
```

The thing is that for other pages the variable is set, but not for index.php.
I don't get it. Don't see the error anywhere.

Here's result of print_r($_SESSION):
On other page: Array ( [is_logged_in] => 1 ) 
On Index page: Array ( )

Comment: Where does that `var1` come from?

Comment: Code from index.php it is also in other page?  print_r($_SESSION) in index

Comment: Please, stop using the old `mysql_*()` function. You have been learning from 10 year old tutorials.

Comment: can that be the reason of given malfunction?

Comment: @tereško: Apparently we are [not supposed to discuss that on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8710062/343302).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you generate your session from the http://www.mysite.com And you redirect to http://mysite.com.
Be careful with session. Web site with www. and without aren't same for sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Which variable is not set? I do not see `$_SESSION['var1']` anywhere on that page. Session variables will be available only after you set them, so you could not expect `$_SESSION['is_logged_in']` to be set on the first page that the visitor lands on.

Answer (score 0):

Is that PHP block first in index.php?  If the HTML form is before that block, then PHP won't be able to send the session cookie in the response header.